# Apex test to imitate closing a case + inserting a case comment

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, order-of-execution

When using the standard Close Case button, you can provide an optional case comment. When a user provides a comment, the order of execution is somewhat peculiar. This caused us some troubles and I want to write an apex test that covers this use case.

Is there a way to simulate that a user **closes a case and adds a comment in one transaction** in apex, as they do when using the Close Case button?

This is different from changing the status to Closed, updating the case, and then inserting a comment, or the other way round. I'll explain this by comparing the order of execution when closing a case vs. closing a case and providing a comment.

The order of execution when you close a case without a comment (nothing surprising here):

1. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
2. Validation:Case
3. Case trigger event AfterUpdate
4. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
5. Validation:Case
6. Case trigger event AfterUpdate
7. Workflow:Case
8. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
9. Case trigger event AfterUpdate

The order of execution when you provide a comment:

1. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
2. Validation:Case
3. Workflow:CaseComment
4. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
5. Validation:Case
6. Case trigger event AfterUpdate
7. Case trigger event AfterUpdate
8. Workflow:Case
9. Case trigger event BeforeUpdate
10. Case trigger event AfterUpdate

What confuses me here is that after step 2, there is no AfterUpdate trigger, but a workflow rule, which causes another BeforeUpdate event. Maybe the standard order of execution is not followed when using the Close Case page with a comment.

Comment: The narrow answer to your question is of course YES -- in one transaction you can use Apex to a) insert the `CaseComment` and then b) update the `Case` to closed. For example, if doing through a VF controller, you can set a savepoint and then if any exception occurs on the Case update, rollback the `CaseComment` insert.

Comment: I tried this: Test.startTest(); insert comment; testCase.Status = 'Closed';  update testCase; Test.stopTest(); Unfortunately, this has a different order of execution than doing the same via the Close Case button. The test passes, but a test in the GUI fails.

Comment: I could not solve the problem that the behaviour of "Close Case" causes, but my users did not need this button, so I removed it.